# Which method is better for incrementing and traversing in a loop in C

Tags: c

These are example of incrementing each element of an array by 10.

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i++){
    arr[i] += 10;
}
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i+=2){
    arr[i] += 10;
    arr[i+1] += 10;
}
```

which is the efficient way to solve this problem out of these these two in C language?

Comment: As everytime with performance questions: measure it! Don't trust a theory, measure the real code. In your case it is very likely that your compiler will know it better and generate code that you don't expect. It may be identical in both cases.

Comment: If you care that much about optimization you'd express it in the simplest possible form so the compiler can better understand your intent. Check the assembly output of a fully-optimized build (`-O3`) for more detail.

Comment: Trust your compilers optimizer (It is probably smarter than you in any case). It likely doesn't make *any* difference. Just write the clearest, most readable code you can. Also, use a *profiler* if you really care.

Comment: If you do not measure, you're just guessing.  Even though you might be trying to achieve better performance at the expense of legibility & maintainability by second-guessing the compiler's optimizer, without measuring... you don't know.  You may just as easily have pessimized your code.

Comment: Even further, clang (probably gcc too, but I didn't need to learn about it) has a pragma to indicate you want it to unroll a loop, if you're unsure. Note also you need to take care of not unrolling so much that your code spans two or more cache lines, otherwise you risk losing performance due to a cache miss.

Comment: @S.M. while C and C++ have major differences, I don't see how the answer would be different for this particular question. Care to explain in more depth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @JeremyRoman stated compiler will be better than the humans optimizing the code.

But you may make its work easier or tougher. In your example the second way prevents gcc from unrolling the loops.

So make it simple, do not try to premature micro optimize your code as result might be right opposite than expected

https://godbolt.org/z/jYcLpT

Comment: "compiler will be better than the humans optimizing the code". This is a good rule of thumb, but it's not always the case. The average programmer will most likely be worse than the compiler, except for algorithm optimization (the compiler won't pick the right data structure for you). However, expert assembly programmers tend to beat the compiler, at the expense of making the code harder to understand and non-portable. Of course, the compiler easily matches an expert for easy code.

Comment: *`However, expert assembly programmers`* I have stopped reading from here. Good luck in writing programs in assembler. BTW it is not the truth as well. It is very unlikely programmers to remember all of thousands of machine code instructions and their usage to make code more efficient than the compiler does.

Comment: @P__J__: Re “Good luck in writing programs in assembler”: Engineers in Apple’s Vector and Numerics Group do it every day. And they do not have to remember thousands of instructions; they have manuals that document them. Re “I have stopped reading from here”: That is not a good technique for learning.

Comment: @EricPostpischil some very specialized programming where compilers are not good. BTW thanks god after the 8051 era I do not have to program in assembler which is one of the most boring things I can imagine.  In the last 10 years I wrote maybe 200-300 lines in assembler (mainly when was working on the RTOS scheduler)

Comment: You don't generally write *programs* in assembly. You write the hotpots, after you measure, and you measure the result afterwards. Many video codecs have handmade SIMD assembly implementations. BTW, you don't need to remember all of the thousands of machine code instructions, you use a manual for that. I am not advocating assembly as the go-to language *at all*. I'm saying there are certain contexts where it is the right tool.

Comment: FWIW, I avoid assembly like the plague. I'm just grateful some people specialize in that for the places that matter.

Comment: @P__J__: Re “some very specialized programming where compilers are not good”: The reason expert assembly programmers are used primarily in “specialized” programming is not because it is where compilers are not good but because of the cost. An expert can beat a compiler in many circumstances, not just specialized ones. But it is expensive, so the special circumstances where it is useful are not where a compiler is particularly bad but where the code in question is of particular importance for performance, such as  heavily used routines.

Comment: Another example of hand-crafted assembly in current projects is crypto: "As a side benefit, ECDSA is lightning fast, and our engineer Vlad Krasnov actually helped make it even faster. By implementing ECDSA natively in assembler, he was able to speed up signing by 21x." taken from https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-deep-dive-into-dns-packet-sizes-why-smaller-packet-sizes-keep-the-internet-safe/. AFAIK, the Linux kernel also provides assembly optimized code in their crypto libraries.

Comment: @Oppen I would rather not relay on the big programs or libraries written in assembler. Assembler code is so hard to maintain and error prone. Examples of some assembly code actually prove the rule.

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry about it. Your compiler will make this optimization if necessary.

For example, [clang 10 unrolls this completely and uses vector instructions to do multiple at once](https://godbolt.org/z/TMoeV9).

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at *better* and *efficient* outside of run-time performance<sup>1</sup>.

**Bug!**

Only 3 or 4 lines of code and the one with 4 is incorrect.  What if `arr[]` and `ar[]` both existed? the compiler would not complain, yet certainly incorrect code.

```
//ar[i+1] += 10;
arr[i+1] += 10;
```

**Coding**

The below wins. Short and and easy to code.  No concern about if  `arr[i+1] += 10;` access `arr[100]`

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i++){
  arr[i] += 10;
}
```

**Review**

The below wins. Clear, to the point.  I had to review the other more to be clear of its correctness - inefficient review time.  Defense-ability - I'd have no trouble defending this code.

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
  arr[i] += 10;
}
```

**Maintenance**

The below wins. Change `i < 100` to `i < N` and this code is fine, the other can readily break.

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
  arr[i] += 10;
}
```

**Optimization possibilities**

The below wins. Compilers do a fine job at optimizing common idioms.  The 2nd poses more analyses and a greater chance the compiler will not optimize well.

```
for (i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
  arr[i] += 10;
}
```

**Score**

Outside of performance:

5 to 0

---

<sup>1</sup> Notice OP never explicitly stated to view this only as run-time performance. So let use consider various ideas of better.

Comment: I agree, but 0 seems a bit harsh. There's always the case of a niche compiler that doesn't do so well (emphasis on *niche*). I had the pleasure of using Borland C++ 3.1 until 2017 (yes, really). I didn't need to optimize much, but I did need to workaround some bugs that will obviously never be fixed, thus I wouldn't expect it to be as smart as current clang or gcc in general, and specifically optimizing. So, explicit, after measuring, may be better for performance on poor compilers. I'd give it one point for that.

Comment: @Oppen My answer concerns about the aspects aside from performance.  A weakness to measuring performance is that it compares the code approaches with a target platform and  a target compiler of today.  Other platforms, compilers of today and all tomorrow ones the results may differ.  True there are _select_ cases for throwing all resources at making a given case more optimized.  Had OP spec'd the target processor, compiler, and larger context, I might have more agreed with you.  Here I see it as _error_ prone and counter to letting the compiler do its job.

Comment: This was a very interesting analysis. Would you recommend any free books for such code reviews?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214077/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-ardent-coder).

Comment: "My answer concerns about the aspects aside from performance." I'm aware, that's why I agree on the winner. It's error prone and platform bound, just as my example was about. But a 0 sounds to me like you wouldn't use it *anywhere ever*. I like your analysis a lot, both in the answer and the comments (I find your comments quite enlightening, actually).